# Using "or" inside a conditional statement in Python: "if x == "y" or "z""

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

```
def shapearea():
    shape = raw_input("What shape do you want to print? ")
    if shape == "triangle" or "Triangle":
        return trianglearea()

    elif shape == "circle" or "Circle":
        return circlearea()

    elif shape == "square" or "Square":
        return squarearea()
    else:
        shapearea()

shapearea()
```

Using this code breaks my program, how can I get the program to register (for example):

"circle" OR "Circle" as the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if shape in ("triangle", "Triangle")
```

or better yet,

```
if shape.lower() == "triangle"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @jamylak's answer, Here is what you need:

```
if shape == "triangle" or shape == "Triangle":
    return trianglearea()

elif shape == "circle" or shape == "Circle":
    return circlearea()

elif shape == "square" or shape == "Square":
    return squarearea()
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's working as I intended now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
So the actual function should be:  
def shapearea():
shape = raw_input("What shape do you want to print? ")
        if shape == "triangle" or shape == "Triangle":
            return trianglearea()

    elif shape == "circle" or shape == "Circle":
        return circlearea()

    elif shape == "square" or shape == "Square":
        return squarearea()
    else:
        shapearea()

shapearea()
```